# random team generator with varying number of teams

Tags: python

So I am about to learn how to code in python and therefore I am trying to make a random team generator as shown below.

Currently, I have an output. However, the output I have is not how I want it to be.
I have looked for a way to save the data from the while loop and export it out to the list created in the for loop and save the data each time. However, this seems to be an impossible assignment.

```
#team selector
import random
player_list=[]
players=int(input('input number of players: '))
teams= int(input('input number of teams: '))

if players<teams:
    print('to many teams, to few players')
else:
    
    for i in range(0, players):
        names =input('input player {0}: '.format(i+1))
        player_list.append(names)
    print(player_list)
    
    while len(player_list)>0:
        for i in range(0, teams):
            q=i+1
            teamq=[]
            
            while len(player_list)>0:
                z=i+1
                playerz=random.choice(player_list)
                teamq.append(playerz)
                player_list.remove(playerz)
                break
                
                if player_list==[]:
                    break
         
            print('team {0} is '.format(q), teamq)
```

**so currently my output is for instance**

```
input number of players: 5
input number of teams: 3
input player 1: James
input player 2: peter
input player 3: john
input player 4: ann
input player 5: Jackson
['James', 'Peter', 'John', 'Ann', 'Jackson']
team 1 is  ['Peter']
team 2 is  ['Jackson']
team 3 is  ['James']
team 1 is  ['Ann']
team 2 is  ['John']
team 3 is  []
```

**And what I want is**

```
input number of players: 5
input number of teams: 3
input player 1: James
input player 2: peter
input player 3: john
input player 4: ann
input player 5: Jackson
['James', 'Peter', 'John', 'Ann', 'Jackson']
team 1 is  ['Peter', 'Ann']
team 2 is  ['Jackson', 'John']
team 3 is  ['James']
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Try to use `random.sample()`. 
`import math`
`playerz=random.sample(player_list, min(math.ceil(players/teams), len(player_list))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try mine below.

Note that I added some comments and gave some changes to variable names in the code.

```
import random, sys

# multiple assignment
players, p, teams = [], int(input('input number of players: ')), int(input('input number of teams: '))

if p < teams:
    # if this block is true, print message and 
    # finish program instead of going through codes below
    print('too many teams, too few players')
    sys.exit()

for i in range(p):
    n = input('input player {}: '.format(i+1))
    n = n[0].upper() + n[1:] # first letter of each name capitalised 
    players.append(n)
print(players)

# make an empty list and inside it append each empty list
# length of teams times using list comprehension.
# use _ when you don't ever use it
team_g = [list() for _ in range(teams)]

while len(players) > 0:
    for i in range(teams):
        p=random.choice(players)
        team_g[i].append(p)
        players.remove(p)
        if not players: # if players is empty 
            break
    continue # to prevent infinite loop

for i in range(teams):
    print( 'Team {} is {}'.format(i+1, team_g[i]) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry,Dear it works for only those number when player is exactly divisible by team:

e.g. player = 6

team = 3

```
import random
player_list=[]
players=int(input('input number of players: '))
teams= int(input('input number of teams: '))

if players<teams:
    print('to many teams, to few players')
else:
    for i in range(0, players):
        names =input('input player {0}: '.format(i+1))
        player_list.append(names)
    print(player_list)
    
max_members = players//teams

teams_2d_list = [[] for i in range(teams)]


for i in range(teams):
    for j in range(max_members):
        if len(player_list) == 0:
            break
        a_rand_player = player_list.pop(random.randint(0,len(player_list)-1)) 
        #get a random element from player_list them pop/remove it 
        teams_2d_list[i].append(a_rand_player)
print("\n",teams_2d_list)
        
for i in range(teams):
    print("team{} ".format(i),"is ",teams_2d_list[i])
```

Output:

```
[['bcd', 'abc'], ['jkp', 'sour'], ['def', 'fgh']]
team0 is ['bcd', 'abc']
team1 is ['jkp', 'sour']
team2 is ['def', 'fgh']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution that uses random.choices (to create list of teams) and defaultdict (to link teams and players):

Import packages and initialize variables:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from random import choices

players = ['James', 'Peter', 'John', 'Ann', 'Jackson']

# ensure every team has at least one member
teams = ['team-1', 'team-2', 'team-3']

# and add random teams, so len(teams) == len(players)
teams += choices(teams, k = len(players) - len(teams))

# each value in the default dict is a list (initially empty)
roster = defaultdict(list)
```

Now assign each player to a team; `roster` is a defaultdict such that values are lists; it's from the built-in `collections` package.

```
for team, player in zip(teams, players):
    roster[team].append(player)
```

Finally, show the members of each team:

```
for team in sorted(set(teams)):
    print(team, '\t', roster[team])

team-1   ['James', 'Jackson']
team-2   ['Peter', 'Ann']
team-3   ['John']
```